# Code Igniter Pass Dynamic Associative Array to Model

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model-view-controller, dynamic, associative

I am trying to pass an dynamic associate array, but cannot figure it out.  The code below is not correct, but that's something similar to what I am trying to do:

Controller:

```
$day = $this->input->post('day');

$schedule = array(
                'user_id' => $this->input->post('name'),
                '$day' => $this->input->post('day')
             );
```

Model:

```
$this->db->insert('work_schedule', $schedule);
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong for your `$day` variable

```
$day = $this->input->post('day');

$schedule = array(
            'user_id' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'day' => $day
         ); //you have stored your $day variable already. Do not try to do it again
```

Model

First of all `var_dump` your `$schedule` array in model to verify is your data receiving in the model or not

```
$this->db->insert('work_schedule', $schedule);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am trying to make $day =>$day in the array.  For example:

I am grabbing the day from a form in the view. 

Let's just say "tuesday" is the value passed in from the form in view

$day = 'Tuesday'; 

$schedule = array(
            'user_id' => $this->input->post('name'),
            '$day' =>  $this->input->post('day'),
         );


I want print_r($schedule) to output:

Comment: explain this please...!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am trying to make $day =>$day in the array.  For example:

I am grabbing the day from a form in the view. 

Let's just say "tuesday" is the value passed in from the form in view

    $day = 'Tuesday'; 

    $schedule = array(
            'user_id' => $this->input->post('name'),
            '$day' =>  $this->input->post('day'),
         );

I would like to insert:

    INSERT INTO `work_schedule` (`user_id`, `tuesday`) VALUES ('1', 'tuesday');

Sorry, didn't get to finish. The edit form timed out on me earlier.

Comment: remove single quotes from around $day

Comment: I've tried many variations of passing through "day" (including removing single quotes). It worked this time around, but after I found a typo/not passing the correct field to model. Wasted so much time with the nooobie mistake. Thanks for your help!!